# bootstrap multiple image gallery leaves a space in between

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I am trying to make a gallery with multiple image along with the name below it.

Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <a  href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.example.com/img" >
      </br>
      <span>name</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This displays the different sized images and with random gaps in between rows and columns. How can I fix it and get all images structures properly. I want to open a page when I click on the image not image gallery.

Comment: This is because, bootstarp classes `col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6` has its own `left and right` padding. Might be all of your image will not have same `height` and `width`, hence you are getting inconsistent gap between the images. The solution for your problem is, give specific `height` and `width ` to the image through image. So that consistent gap will appear

Answer (score 0):

Give a fix width to the divs

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 fix-width">
    <a  href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.example.com/img" >
      </br>
      <span>name</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.fix-width { width:200px;}
```

Comment: yes. I have to add height also. Is there a plugin that can handle this?